# Logical/Etymological reason for unique conjugation of third person singular present tense

Tags: etymology, historical-change, inflectional-morphology, grammatical-person

In most English verbs, there is a consistent pattern in the conjugation of present and past tense.  For past tense, the same inflection is used for each grammatical person, but in present tense, third person singular stands apart from the rest.

For example, with **run**:

> **Past tense**: I ran / you ran / we ran / they ran / she ran
>
> **Present tense**: I run / you run / we run / they run / ***she runs***

There is an exception, which is **To be**.  The pattern of unique conjugation for the third person singular present tense can be seen in this chart, along with the irregularity of *to be*.

[image]

Setting aside **to be** (at least for now), is there a logical or etymological reason for the unique conjugation of the third person singular present tense?

Comment: And `{-Z₁}`, the English third person singular present tense suffix -- one of  [the 8 inflections left in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf), and one of three that all use /z/, /s/, and /əz/ -- is  the only mark of present tense around (everything else can be taken for an infinitive, and often is in nascent Englishes). So that suffix, and the subsequent worry about "is XYZ singular or plural?" becomes a status symbol, like _whom_, and is often mistaken and frequently omitted. That's the way the cookie crumbles, etymologically speaking.

Comment: In other words, why is there NO distinction between the different subjects in any of the "tenses" excluding the present tense? Which helps to explain why including the subject in English is almost always obligatory. This is not nearly so important in Italian, e.g. *andai* (I went), *andasti* (you went), *andò* (s/he went), *andammo* (we went), *andaste* (you went (pl)), *andarono* (they went). English is "logical" in the sense it has simplified greatly this aspect of language. What could be easier than remembering one word, "went", for all the subjects?

Comment: @Mari-LouA having a person marker of inflection on verbs doesn't necessarily mean that the language is pro-drop. Eg French. (that means, French inflects verbs for person but you still can't drop the pronoun it agrees with).

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime 'why' questions are hard to answer because languages aren't designed, so you can't answer why did the designer put this feature in. All you can really do is describe things in multiple languages and compare and contrast among them. Then a 'why' question might really be answered sufficiently by a 'by what process?' or 'what was the trend?'.

Comment: So the real answer, to what I think your question is (which I think is 'Why is 3rd person singular the only thing with an extra ending (where Spanish has every person marked and Chinese has none)?'), is 'Because English used to have all of them (in OE) but lost them (mostly) after 1066 probably because of [creolization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creolization) with French.'

Comment: RE: creolization...that is both speculative (with some support, with other alternatives) and also doesn't explain a similar situation in other languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*As this is a very broad question whose full answer merits several written
books, I ﬁrst present a brief orientation and outline of how we got here today, with pointers to more detailed material.*

---

Closely related to this question are questions like these, some of which you may have actually been asking about indirectly:

- Why is it *‑s* not *‑xyzzy* or *‑rumplestiltskin*?
- Why is it pronounced three ways?
- Why is it sometimes spelled diﬀerently than other times?
- Why isn’t it always “spelled the way it’s pronounced”?
- What’s its relationship to its two sound-alikes, the plural inﬂection for nouns and the possessive enclitic?
- Why don’t we have this in other persons and tenses or nonﬁnite forms?
- Why don’t we have this in the preterite?
- Why don’t we have this in the modals?
- Why doesn’t the required subject suﬃce to say which person it is?
- Why do we have this at all?
- Since the plural of *lives* is *live*, why then isn’t the plural of *has* just plain **ha* — and all the rest like that?

In those questions as well as in the one which I believe was asked, [synchronic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrony_and_diachrony) fails to provide a satisfying answer, or really any at all in most cases. Instead one must examine the language diachronically to draw out a sensible answer, and a full treatment of that answer must reach back over six millennia.

Languages with mainly [unbound morphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_and_unbound_morphemes) — atomic units of meaning at the
lexemic level only — are classiﬁed as [analytic languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_language), while those
whose individual words each comprise multiple bound morphemes are
classiﬁed as [synthetic languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_language).

An individual word in a synthetic language combines several bound morphemes
where each little internal piece adds something to the word’s overall
meaning.  Morphological inﬂection can occur via [aﬃxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix) (*give* > *giving*, *ox* > *oxen*, *walk* > *walked*), via 
sound changes of [vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophony) or [consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonant_mutation#English) (*give* > *gave*, *shoot* > *shot*, *man* > *men*, *mouse* > *mice*, *this* > *these*), or via both (*brother* > *brethren*, *swell* > *swollen*, *give* > *gavest*).

Today’s English is for the most part an analytic language. For meaning, we
rely far more strongly on ﬁxed word-order and on little “function” words (including
auxiliary verbs, articles and other determiners, conjunctions, and prepositions) than we do on
synthesis via inﬂectional morphology the way synthetic languages do.

At the same time, English still has a few inﬂections left in it thanks to its
ultimate derivation from a long genetic line of highly synthetic languages stretching back over 6,000 years. We can trace English’s ancestors all the way to the prehistoric (read: unwritten)
[Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) (PIE) language of our distant ancestors. That language
was strongly synthetic in all its open word classes, including in its [verb
forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_verbs#Active_eventive_endings).

One distinctive PIE verb inﬂection that occurred in certain verbs’ third-person present
singular conjugations was **‑t* or **‑ti*. This became in prehistoric
[Proto-Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_grammar#Class_2)
**‑di* or **‑þi*, in [Old
English](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Old_English/Verbs#Example_of_a_verb)
*‑(e)þ*, in [Middle 
English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English#Verbs) *‑(e)þ*, and in
[Early Modern 
English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English#Marking_tense_and_number)
the *‑(e)th* of *he live**th***, which passed quickly enough into the distinctive
inﬂection you’ve asked about, the *‑(e)s* form of *he live**s*** or *he itch**es*** in today’s
English.

PIE third-person singular inﬂections also produced forms like German
*er bleib**t***, Latin *mane**t*** or *cōnsta**t***, Old French *il remain**t***, and
although you can no longer normally hear it pronounced in speech, also in the
imperfect *il restai**t*** of today’s French (but no longer in its present
tense sauf in certain relics such as subjunctive *qu’il soi**t*** for “that he/it should be”).

Old English was a much more synthetic language than Middle English was, which saw dramatic reductions in inﬂections as the language transitioned to 
an analytic one. There are several proposed explanations for why this happened, but that’s a whole nother topic with its own lines of investigation. Suﬃce it to say that Middle English was a furious time of mergers and acquisitions that saw as sweeping changes to the grammar as to the lexicon.

Similarly to how Middle English remade synthetic Old English analytically by reducing inﬂections across the board, 
Early Modern English verbs did enjoy more conjugations than today’s English does, but
these again underwent rapid evolution.  From [the Wikipedia article on that topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English#Marking_tense_and_number)
we read:

> ### Verbs
>
> #### Marking tense and number
>
> During the Early Modern period, English verb inﬂections became simpliﬁed
>   as they evolved towards their modern forms:
>
> - The third person singular present lost its alternate inﬂections:
>     *‑(e)th* became obsolete while *‑s* survived. (The alternate forms’
>     coexistence can be seen in Shakespeare’s phrase, “With her, that *hateth*
>     thee and *hates* us all”).
> - The plural present form became uninﬂected. Present plurals had been
>     marked with *‑en*, *‑th*, or *‑s* (*‑th* and *‑s* survived the longest,
>     especially with the plural use of *is*, *hath*, and *doth*). Marked present
>     plurals were rare throughout the Early Modern period, though, and *‑en* was
>     probably only used as a stylistic aﬀectation to indicate rural or
>     old-fashioned speech.
> - The second person singular was marked in both the present and past tenses
>     with *‑st* or *‑est* (for example, in the past tense, *walkedst* or
>     *gav’st*).  Since the indicative past was not (and is not) otherwise marked
>     for person or number, the loss of *thou* made the past subjunctive
>     indistinguishable from the indicative past for all verbs except *to be*.

I reckon that that’s as detailed an answer to a rather broad
question as one dare  get here.

I in passing note that English does
retain a single, unique inﬂectional distinction in the past indicative’s singular *was* versus its plural *were* (which is also the past subjunctive irrespective of number). Verbs other than *be* are no longer so marked.

---

#### Postamble

Lastly, in John Lawler’s comment:

> And `{‑Z₁}`, the English third person singular present tense suﬃx —
>   one of [the 8 inﬂections left in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf),
>   and one of three that all use /z/, /s/, and /əz/ — is the only mark of
>   present tense around (everything else can be taken for an inﬁnitive, and
>   often is in nascent Englishes). So that suﬃx, and the subsequent worry
>   about “is XYZ singular or plural?” becomes a status symbol, like *whom*,
>   and is often mistaken and frequently omitted. That’s the way the cookie
>   crumbles, etymologically speaking.

When John writes {‑Z₁} using an [archiphonemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme#Neutralization_and_archiphonemes) {Z}, what he means is that
that morphological inﬂection ends up being pronounced in three slightly diﬀerent ways depending on its surrounding phonologic environment:

1. *kits* has /s/
2. *kids* has /z/
3. *kitches* has /əz/

Moreover, we use that same {Z} archiphoneme for three of English’s eight
remaining inﬂections:

1. First we use it for present-tense verbs’
   third-person singular infﬂections.
2. Second we use it for the plural
   inﬂections of singular nouns.
3. And third we use it for possessives formed
   via enclitic.

All three of these follow the same pronunciation rules to
translate archiphonemic {Z} into actual phonetics.  (Please don’t worry about
the spelling; spelling is merely an immaterial side-eﬀect of writing technology, and so
shouldn’t be paid any attention to here since we’re talking about language not technology.)

Comment: I’m going to start conjugating all my regular verbs in 3sg with _-rumplestiltskin_ from now on. That strikerumplestiltskin me as a brilliant way of simplifying the overload of the /z/ suffix.