# Why do my legs (plural) ache (singular) but my back (singular) aches (plural)

Tags: agreement

I couldn't think how to word the title without writing my whole question, I am a native English speaker so while I understand saying "my legs aches" is wrong and sounds weird, I have no idea why. Same as saying "my back ache" is also weird.

- "Leg" without an -s is the singular while "legs" with an -s is the plural.
- "Ache" without an -s expects plural agreement while "aches" with an -s expects singular agreement.

Why do the singular (and respectively, plural) forms not agree in terms of '-s' or 'no -s'?

Comment: The third person singular present indicative usually adds an *-s* in English.  For example *he eats* while *they eat*. Similarly *you write* but *she writes*.  See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405449/logical-etymological-reason-for-unique-conjugation-of-third-person-singular-pres

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U. I've edited your question to highlight what appears to be its intent. Please feel free to [edit] further or to roll back the changes.

Comment: This question, as originally formulated, manifested a simple misunderstanding, which was corrected by the two answers below. After the edit, it seems to be asking why is adding and *s* used for two entirely different purposes in English: forming the plural of a noun, and forming the third-person singular of a verb. Chances are that this new question is unanswerable (although it would be really exciting if it turned out that there is an answer to it).

Comment: Pity. I believe that the question should have been migrated  to ELL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight misconception in your title.

> Your legs (plural) *ache* and your back (singular) *aches*.

*ache* and *aches* are **not** singular and plural, respectively. *aches* merely has the third-person-singular -s ending in conjugating verbs in the present tense:

> I ache
>   you ache
>   he/she/it **aches**
>   we ache
>   you ache
>   they ache

In your example, *legs ache* is the plural third person, while *back aches* is singular third person.
It is just one of the many exceptions in English that we just have to remember.

Comment: Apologies - I edited the OP's question while you were formulating your answer. The question now references singular/plural *agreement* for the verb. You may wish to update your answer.

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks for the hint, but I think the answer can stand as it is. If you see any additional remarks that improve the answer, feel free to make an edit!

Answer (score 1):

The word *ache* in "my legs ache" is a *verb*, it is not a noun.

You can have ***a*** **backache** (back-ache), and ***a*** **headache**, but when a part of your body is hurting you or complains of a dull constant pain, we say that ***it*** (singular pronoun) ***aches***.

> My shoulders (pl. n) **ache** from bending hours over my laptop
>   My back (s. n) **aches** after painting the ceiling